# django - apache integration

Tags: django, apache

Im tired of trying to put this working :(
So, here is my problem:

Added to httpd.conf :

`Location "/ps3t/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ps3t.settings
    PythonOption django.root /ps3t
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/fabriciols'] + sys.path"
/Location>`

- removed the "<" from localtion, but on my httd.conf have

but, when i access my site :

```
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 228, in handler
    return ModPythonHandler()(req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 191, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 268, in __getattr__
    self._setup()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)

ImportError: Could not import settings 'ps3t.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named ps3t.settings
```

my project structure :

```
/home/fabriciols/ - root dir
./ps3t            - project
./ps3t/myps3t     - app
```

every user has read perm in all files ...

what im doing wrong ? :/

Comment: Is there a good reason you're using mod_python? That has problems with unpredictable memory usage; mod_wsgi is the recommended choice.

Comment: because I didnt know:)
installed on my server now and I will use to see if it's good.
he is so much better than mod_python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the solution, but i thing this isnt the best solution

`chmod +rx -R /home/fabriciols/`

i read that apache only need READ perm on dir, but it seems to need execute perm too :D

Comment: Execute permission means that apache can read the contents of that dir, otherwise it can't get a listing.